# Storage size of array.array in a file

Tags: python, file-io

I'm using `array.array`to store many fixed-size numerical records in binary format to a large file, which I would like to process in parallel in chunks, by writing e.g `array.array('l', range(20)).tofile(fout)`. How can I calculate the offsets to use with `seek` to ensure that I chunk at record boundaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take an `array` object:

```
>>> import array
>>> a = array.array('l', range(20))
```

The size of each element, in bytes:

```
>>> a.itemsize
4
```

Write it out:

```
>>> f = open('array.dat', "wb")
>>> a.tofile(f)
>>> f.close()
```

Sanity check:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.stat('array.dat').st_size
80L
>>> len(a) * a.itemsize
80
```

So the file has the expected number of bytes.  Read up the value at "index", say, 7:

```
>>> f = open('array.dat', 'rb')
>>> f.seek(7 * a.itemsize)
>>> raw = f.read(a.itemsize)
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack(a.typecode, raw)
(7,)
```

Clear?

Comment: Crystal. I ended up doing essentially this: why use struct instead of array.fromfile?

Comment: `fromfile()` is fine! But I figured you already knew that, since you already found `tofile()`. `struct` adds to your bag of tricks :-)  For example, `struct` can be used to extract a slice of arbitrary length from anywhere in the file, without needing to read the whole file.